# How tall is Vice Admiral Smoker?

Tags: one-piece

How tall is Vice Admiral Smoker?

I've used [Wikia](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Main_Page) as a reference. They have the most information out there by a long shot. The heights of various characters are usually shown there.

Another resource that is useful is the SBS, perhaps it's stated on there?

Comment: may i ask why you have asked this question

Answer (score 2):

All I found online was [a forum thread on Oro Jackson](http://orojackson.com/threads/one-piece-character-heights.10449/page-4) which list the characters with confirmed heights according to the forum's OP. There is no one source for all this: I presume all this info comes from SBS and data books.

Anyway, **Smoker is apparently 185 cm**. This makes sense if we look at the picture below as Zorro's height is 178 cm before the time skip according to the [volume 10 SBS](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/SBS_Volume_10).

[image: a panel with Smoker and Zorro for height comparison]